# Default dependent action when calling destroy in ActiveRecord / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When calling `destroy` on a model in ActiveRecord, I've read it is capable of destroying all associated records, and that functionality appears to be setup by using the `dependent` option when setting up the association.

What I would like to know is - what happens if you **don't** set the option?

For example, in the below code, am I correct in saying:

1. The subscribers would NOT be affected
2. The user would NOT be affected
3. The comments WOULD be destroyed? (and in turn any associations they have marked with `dependent: destroy` would also then follow the same process)

```ruby
class StackOverflowQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :subscribers
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My end goal is to be able to have a model which will destroy *some* associated records, but not necessarily all of them, as destroying all the associations would mean that data that is reference by other records would start to get wiped out (such as in this example, I'd not want a user to be deleted if their question was deleted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is correct.  But you should be aware that the `subscribers` records will be orphaned.  If they are set up with a `had_many` relation, as you show, then each `subscriber` record contains a foreign key that is the id of the `StackOverflowQuestion` record, which will no longer exist after you destroy it.  So it will point to an invalid record.

Answer (score 1):

> The subscribers would NOT be affected

This depends on how you define your schema with the foreign key. There are 2 cases here:

**Case 1**: You define you schema like this:

```
create_table :subscribers do |t|
  t.integer :stack_overflow_question_id
  # other fields
end
add_index :subscribers, :stack_overflow_question_id
add_foreign_key :subscribers, :stack_overflow_question, column: :stack_overflow_question_id
```

This means you set the foreign key constraint for `stack_overflow_question_id`, so when you delete a `StackOverflowQuestion`, if there is any `Subscriber` which has the foreign key referring to that `StackOverflowQuestion`, **rails will give you an error**, this makes sense because you are referring a record to a deleted record!

**Case 2**: Define like `Case 1` but without foreign key constraint

**Rails won't give you any error**, but you will smell wrong with the data, there are some records referring to the deleted records, this should be avoided

> The user would NOT be affected

This makes sense because this is `belongs_to` relation, `user` wouldn't be affected.

> The comments WOULD be destroyed? (and in turn any associations they
>   have marked with dependent: destroy would also then follow the same
>   process)

Yes, this is how rails works

**Summary**
You may redefine like this:

```
class StackOverflowQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :subscribers, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Hence, your `subscribers` 's foreign key will be set to `NIL` when you destroy `StackOverflowQuestion`, and there isn't any foreign key which is not nil and invalid!